# Calling a method inside another method and passing a parameter in a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

The first method has a condition of the query and it returns the count of the query specified.The 2nd method calls the 1st method. First question, how can i pass the parameter **$compid** to Method countEmployee from Method userSummary? Second question, Is this the right thing to call method countEmployee inside method userSummary?

> 1st Method

```
public function countEmployee($compid){
                    $query = User::query();
                    $company = $query;
                    // $thgarments = $query;
                    $company->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                        $q->where('company_id','=', $compid);
                    });
                    $company->where('emp_status','=', 'Regular');
                    $totalemployee = $company->count();

                    return $totalemployee;
    }
```

> 2nd Method

```
public function userSummary()
{
     $tenghwa = countEmployee(2);
}
```

Comment: *a method inside another method* wait what? could you show which class the `userSummary` and `countEmployee` methods belong to? *how can i pass the parameter $compid to Method countEmployee from Method userSummary* -- yes, you can pass it as parameter just like how you did already. *Is this the right thing to call method countEmployee inside method userSummary* -- not really, if the `countEmployee` on another class, you will need to  mention the class name, and learn the difference between instance methods and static methods.

Comment: They're on the same class. Is it possible?

Comment: if they are on the same class, yes you can call them that way.

Comment: It gives me an error of "Call to undefined function Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web\countEmployee()" @BagusTesa

Comment: `Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web\countEmployee()`, wait, does by any chance the `Web` is a folder (`namespace`)? you could try `$this->countEmployee(2)` to at least assert that you call the other method within the same class.

Comment: Yes Web is a folder

Comment: What does $this means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174846/discussion-between-gwapo-and-bagus-tesa).

Answer (score 1):

Try this corrected code

```
public function countEmployee($compid) 
{
     $query = User::query();

     $totalemployee = $query->whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($compid) {
         $q->where('company_id','=', $compid);
     })->where('emp_status','=', 'Regular')
     ->count();

    return $totalemployee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function countEmployee($compid){
                    $query = User::query();
                    $company = $query;
                    // $thgarments = $query;
                    $company->whereHas('company', function ($q) use($compid) {
                        $q->where('company_id','=', $compid);
                    });
                    $company->where('emp_status','=', 'Regular');
                    $totalemployee = $company->count();

                    return $totalemployee;
    }

    public function userSummary()
    {
         $tenghwa = $this->countEmployee(2);
    }
```

I realized my mistake. I should "use" $compid in the first method, and in the second method i should put a $this to calling the countEmployee method.

Comment: Oh you meant `closures` [Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)